# Why does regex replace my feed string once + 3 times?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Interesting situation I have here. I have some files in a folder that all have a very explicit string in the first line that I always know will be there. Want I want to do is really just append `|DATA_SOURCE_KEY` right after `AVAILABLE_IND`

```
//regex to search for the bb_course_*.bbd files
  string courseRegex = @"BB_COURSES_([C][E][Q]|[F][A]|[H][S]|[S][1]|[S][2]|[S][P])\d{1,6}.bbd";
  string courseHeaderRegex = @"EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND";

//get files from the directory specifed in the GetFiles parameter and returns the matches to the regex
   var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\courseFolder\").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, courseRegex).Success);

//prints the files returned
            foreach (string file in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                File.WriteAllText(file, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(file), courseHeaderRegex, "EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY"));
            }
```

But this code takes the original occurrence of the matching regex, replaces it with my replacement value, and then does it 3 more times.

`EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY|EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY|EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY|EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY`

And I can't figure out why with breakpoints. My loop is running only 12 times to match the # of files I have in the directory. My only guess is that File.WriteAllText is somehow recursively searching itself after replacing the text and re-replacing. If that makes sense. Any ideas? Is it because `courseHeaderRegex` is so explicit?

If I change `courseHeaderRegex` to `string courseHeaderRegex = @"AVAILABLE_IND";`

then I get the correct changes in my files

```
EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY
```

I'd just like to understand why the original way doesn't work.

Comment: "My only guess is that File.WriteAllText is somehow recursively searching itself". That would not be a good guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to escape the | character in courseHeaderRegex:

```
string courseHeaderRegex = @"EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY\|COURSE_ID\|COURSE_NAME\|AVAILABLE_IND";
```

The character | is the Alternation Operator and it will match 'EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY' , 'COURSE_ID' , ,'COURSE_NAME' and 'AVAILABLE_IND', replacing each of them with your substitution string.

Comment: This was it. Thank you. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: I should have known that considering I had just put together the regex on the previous line in Rubular. with the or operators.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
string newString = File.ReadAllText(file)
    .Replace(@"EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND",@"EXTERNAL_COURSE_KEY|COURSE_ID|COURSE_NAME|AVAILABLE_IND|DATA_SOURCE_KEY");
```

just using a simple String.Replace()

Comment: What? Use a plain old string replacement when I could use that cool regex thing? Where do you get those crazy ideas?

Comment: It doesn't write back to the file.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce: Add another line: `File.WriteAllText(file, newString);`